# having trouble instaling ubuntu using a usb boot on pc

Tags: 12.04

I want to instal ubuntu on my pc using a usb.
I changed the bios option so now the boot is from the usb, but when I restart the computer it shows a black page with only this sighn "_" flashing in the top left corner, and nothing hapens when I press any key.

what should I do to make it work?

Comment: How (and on what OS) was the bootable USB created?

Comment: Booting Ubuntu via live USB might take a long while, how long did you wait for Ubuntu to boot? Did you see the Ubuntu logo after say 5-10 minutes? If not, then you might want to try to format your USB to fat32 and use UNetBootin or MultiSystem to create the liveUSB. Also check the links provided by Bryce on his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Format the USB disk and create a boot disk using unetbootin or any other software.. It might help..

Comment: For a more detailed description on how to get a bootable USB stick via windows using unetbootin see this page http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/usb : if you want a detailed description on how to create a bootable USB stick using mac/windows/*ubuntu see this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick : for future question, please provide more details of how and what u used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that your USB stick is the issue here.  If you're sure that it is not malfunctioning, then you should check that it was properly created.  Now, I'm not sure which OS environment you have access to, but here are the links for how to properly create and boot Ubuntu from a USB stick:

- [How to create a bootable USB stick from Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick from Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick from a Mac (OS X)](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)